# How can I execute one function after another in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, function, asynchronous, async-await, google-bigquery

How are you?

I am new to NodeJs development and I would like to know in my example, how can I run a function in a file `index.js` coming from another file.

For better understanding, here is the code that I'm using. This function writes a clients list into a JSON file. That file is required for the second function on `index.js` to run. This JSON must exists because it will update this JSON file.

```
const keys = require("../service.json");
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const fs = require("fs");

async function main() {
    const client = new google.auth.JWT(keys.client_email, null, keys.private_key, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"]);

    client.authorize(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        } else {
            getClients(client).then(function (clients) {
                const data = [];

                for (let index = 0; index < clients[0].data.values.length; index++) {
                    if (clients[0].data.values[index][0] != undefined) {
                        try {
                            let iteration = {
                                name: clients[0].data.values[index][0],
                                id: clients[1].data.values[index][0],
                                value: parseInt(clients[2].data.values[index][0]),
                                value2: "",
                                date: "",
                            };

                            data.push(iteration);
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    }
                }

                fs.writeFileSync("./clients.json", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), finished);

                function finished(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    async function getClients(client) {
        const gsapi = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client });
        const clientsData = [];

        const options = {
            spreadsheetId: "xxx",
            range: "yyy",
        };

        clientsData.push(await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(options));

        options["range"] = "xxx";
        clientsData.push(await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(options));

        options["range"] = "yyy";
        clientsData.push(await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(options));

        return clientsData;
    }

}

module.exports = { main };
```

Here is the `index` file:
The idea is running the first function `getclients.main()`, which will generate the JSON file. After finishing this function, the second one will start, which is the `puppeteerExport.main()`. After that will upload the file to BigQuery with the third function `exportBQ.uploadToBq()`.

```
const exportBQ = require("./modules/exportToBQ");
const getClients = require("./modules/getClients");
const puppeteerExport = require("./modules/puppeteer");

async function main() {
    await getClients.main();
    puppeteerExport.main();
    exportBQ.uploadToBq();
};

main();
```

How can I guarantee that the second function will be executed only after the first one is complete? Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

For await to work you have to return promise from underline function.
Wrap you main function promise and resolve after your json file is ready

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

```
// some processing
resolve();

// reject if something goes wrong
```

});

Comment: Could you help me with an example how can I use in my situation?

Answer (score 0):

The second function will only be executed when the awaited Promise in the first line gets resolved or rejected. So it definitely should execute the second function *after* the first one is finished

Comment: The problem is that when I run this `main()` function from `index.js`, the result is that cannot found this JSON file called `clients.json`.

That's because the first function doesn't finished.